# NavigationLink issue linking to a website

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using `NavigationLink` i'm attempting to make a button that forwards you to a website on safari, but currently i'm getting the issue `Generic struct 'NavigationLink' requires that 'URL' conform to 'View'` from the following line of code

`NavigationLink("Website", destination: URL(string:  "https://www.google.com")!)`

Does anyone know if there's a simple fix to this? tried looking around and didn't find too many resources on it unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Link` instead of `NavigationLink`

`Link` is for websites, `NavigationLink` is for SwiftUI Views.

Comment: I probably should have added this, but I tried Link originally and received "Result of 'Link<Label>' initializer is unused" which led me to believe i would need to use NavigationLink instead sorry!

Comment: @T.Jaggard make sure the `Link` is in the `body` and not inside a method of some kind or on a `Button` `action`.  SwiftUI `View`s have to be in the `body` and not inside of a `Void`

Comment: Oh that may be the issue then, it's currently inside of a button action as shown in one of my other replies. If not inside a button action, how would I get the user to activate it on-click?

Comment: Nevermind got it, it comes as a link already. Clearly a bit flustered by the stupidity of the issue. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @T.Jaggard no problem, if I answered your question can you mark this as the answer? Just click on the green checkmark above.

Comment: @T.Jaggard `openURL` is also an option https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/openurlaction

Answer (score 2):

As I can see there is already a good answer here, but I will add how you should use the `Link`. As mentioned, `NavigationLink` is used for navigation between `SwiftUI` views. `Link` is what you need for opening external links.

```
Link(destination: URL(string:  "https://www.google.com")!) {
    Text("Website")
}
```

Comment: Hey, currently this is exactly how i'm using the link:

```Button(action: {
                            Link("Website", destination: URL(string:  "https://www.google.com")!)
                            //MARK: LINKS NOT WORKING
                        }) {
                            Text("Visit Website")
                        }```

I tried formatting it as you described, but i'm assuming due to it being inside a button, it would need to be wrote differently?

Comment: You don't have to add it inside a button action, write it exactly as i wrote in the answer, as a standalone component. Perceive Link just like a Button.
Just get rid of the Button, and copy paste what i wrote instead